# How i can use the feed module for uploading the images in the image field of the content type?

Tags: 7, feeds

How can I use the feed module for uploading images into the image field of a content type,  using a .csv file and storing the images inside a directory on server?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the url of the image in your csv and the feeds module will import the image.